# MS Active Directory as a simple LDAP server

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I need to test an application that uses an LDAP store to authenticate users.

We need to POC this app with multiple LDAP providers (OpenLDAP, Sun LDAP, Tivoli Directory Server, Microsoft AD etc).

Is it possible to just install MS Active Directory as a plain LDAP on my existing computer network (just like the other LDAP software from IBM, SUN, Open Source)? My existing corporate network is already running an AD so I dont want to mess up any thing

If yes, please direct me to a solution/resource that will help me achieve the above.

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the technology you are looking for is [AD LDS (in 2008 speak)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731868%28WS.10%29.aspx) or [ADAM (in 2003 speak)](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/adam/default.mspx#EMC) There are differences but you can only deploy AD LDS on a 2k8 system.  ADAM can be installed on XP and 2003 (although I haven't tried it on windows 7 or vista I suspect it will work)

Answer (score 1):

You can also install AD on a new Windows server, configuring it as the first domain controller in a new domain in a new forest. It will be entirely standalone, even if it's on the same LAN as your existing AD domain. That way you won't run into any unexpected differences between AD LDS/ADAM and actual AD.